# Parse xml song files in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to parse multiple xml files with songs info in them.
The structure is something like this:

```
<song_info>
 <title>Title1</title>
 <artist>Artist1</artist>
 <lyrics>Sample lyrics</lyrics>
</song_info>
```

The user enters a phrase and I need to search for the phrase in the lyrics tag. If the phrase exists in the lyrics tag, I need to output a link to the song file. How is this done with LINQ? I am using .NET 3.5 . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If each file just contains a single song info you could just do

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("somefile.xml");
string phrase ="lyric";
if(xdoc.Descendants("lyrics").First().Value.Contains(phrase))
{
   //file contains phrase
}
```

Comment: Yes, each xml file contains 1 song!

Answer (score 0):

```
string keyword = "dummy";
List<string> files = new List<string>();
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\lyrics"))
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(file);
    if (doc.SelectSingleNode("/song_info/lyrics").InnerText.Contains(keyword))
    {
        files.Add(file);
    }
}
```